# Search object from JSON PHP [Laravel]

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I have json data like this [Code in here](https://pastebin.com/csg15FRL)

this json result from

```
$path = public_path() . "/users/project/$endpoint/$id_resource.json";
$file = File::get($path);
return $file
```

if i want to search id : 1 with the url : `localhost/show/json?id=1`
and the result is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Name": {
      "FirstName": "Wilmer",
      "LastName": "Crona",
      "FullName": "Mr. Cameron Prosacco"
    },
    "Address": {
      "Address1": "84154 Vickie Burg Apt. 994",
      "Address2": "Suite 339",
      "ZipCode": "89080-0376"
    },
    "Phone": "316-269-7694 x1364"
  }
]
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data='[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "Name": {
      "FirstName": "Wilmer",
      "LastName": "Crona",
      "FullName": "Mr. Cameron Prosacco"
    },
    "Address": {
      "Address1": "84154 Vickie Burg Apt. 994",
      "Address2": "Suite 339",
      "ZipCode": "89080-0376"
    },
    "Phone": "316-269-7694 x1364"
  }
]';


$data=json_decode($data,true);



foreach($data as $row){
    if($row['id']==$_GET['id']){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($row);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

This code will convert the json to array. Due to the fact that your array is multidimensional you need to use a foreach to access the nested arrays. After that a simple `if` will get the job done.

```
http://localhost/scripts/test.php?id=2
```

This is the url i am using and this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [Name] => Array
        (
            [FirstName] => Mercedes
            [LastName] => Kshlerin
            [FullName] => Dr. Kellie Bashirian
        )

    [Address] => Array
        (
            [Address1] => 12638 Cali Spurs
            [Address2] => Suite 353
            [ZipCode] => 76622
        )

    [Phone] => 319-329-3169 x8848
)
```

Comment: Im sorry. I forgot, this json data was taken from a json file in my laravel public

Comment: I saw your picture this is where i got it as well.

Comment: It'd be better to use `return` or `break` in your `foreach` loop as it will iterate through the entire array even if it's found the correct ID. Also, you didn't close the `<pre>` element.

Comment: I fixed the <pre> closing tag you were right. I think that it should go through the whole array just in case there are duplicated values as well. The question did not specify this so i just assumed that we want to check the whole array.

Comment: Thanks @pr1nc3 , i have used ur method and work . thanks

Comment: Glad i helped!!!

Answer (score 1):

try `return collect($temp)->where('id', $request->get('id'))->first();`
where $temp is your json data.

Comment: Im sorry. I forgot, this json data was taken from a json file in public